# In Kohana 3 Is it possible to use Controller_REST and Controller_Template together?

Tags: php, rest, controller, kohana

Right now I'm using Controller_Template would like to have RESTful URLs though, is it possible to use both the controllers together somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PHP does not support multiple inheritance. You will need to extend `Controller_Template` with another class and manually copy the code form `Controller_REST` into it.